# USB camera not identified

Tags: usb, camera, webcam, usb3, fswebcam

I have a laptop camera wired to a USB cable. This camera works properly on my Ubuntu laptop. However, it does not on the pi.

I have a Raspberry PI 4 (4GB) with Raspbian OS lite installed.

I installed **fswebcam** which upon execution gives below error:

```
--- Opening /dev/video0...
stat: No such file or directory
```

I see video10...video16 under /dev.

I checked `dmesg` I don't see any trace of the USB device being plugged in.
Also, `lsusb` command does not list the device.

Some where I found following command `vcgencmd get_camera` which gives: `supported=1 detected=0`

I tried enabling the camera module from `raspi-config` with no changes in the outcome.

Just for the information, below is the output of `dmesg` from **Ubuntu laptop where this camera works**:

[image]

and output of `lsusb`: `Bus 001 Device 014: ID 05ca:18c3 Ricoh Co., Ltd USB2.0 Camera`

**EDIT**

This morning somehow the camera attached message was logged in the `dmesg` but the command `fswebcam` gave following error:

```
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 320x240.
--- Capturing frame...
VIDIOC_DQBUF: No such device
No frames captured.
```

However, the camera still does not show under `lsusb`.
This is completely out of my understanding.

---

Error when I connected again

```
[86585.292297] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 43 using xhci_hcd
[86585.392723] usb 1-1.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[86585.612567] usb 1-1.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[86585.832347] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 43, error -71
[86585.932352] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[86586.068596] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ca, idProduct=18c3, bcdDevice= 0.12
[86586.068617] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[86586.068636] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[86586.068654] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: LOEA11P2BF13831Y06776
[86586.070871] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (05ca:18c3)
[86586.076148] input: USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input6
[86586.217797] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 44
[86586.742365] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
[86586.888646] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ca, idProduct=18c3, bcdDevice= 0.12
[86586.888669] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[86586.888688] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[86586.888705] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: LOEA11P2BF13831Y06776
[86586.890901] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (05ca:18c3)
[86586.896023] input: USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input7
[86587.754272] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 45
[86588.652384] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
[86588.788655] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ca, idProduct=18c3, bcdDevice= 0.12
[86588.788677] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[86588.788695] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[86588.788713] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: LOEA11P2BF13831Y06776
[86588.790873] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (05ca:18c3)
[86588.795971] input: USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input8
[86589.066736] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 46
[86589.512397] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 47 using xhci_hcd
[86589.648675] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ca, idProduct=18c3, bcdDevice= 0.12
[86589.648696] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[86589.648714] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[86589.648732] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: LOEA11P2BF13831Y06776
[86589.650922] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 Camera (05ca:18c3)
[86589.656001] input: USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input9
[86590.090358] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 47
```

Comment: `Some where I found following command` - that has nothing to do with USB cameras

Comment: What messages do you see in `dmesg` on the Pi when you plug in the camera?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Sometimes nothing, other times `device not accepting address 35, error -71`
Last time when I connected, I updated the error in the edit.

Comment: "nothing" is bad. You should at least get messages from the host controller (ehci/xhci) which must add a new device to the bus. If there are no such messages, there's zero chance for the USB device to work. "device not accepting address" is almost just as bad: the host controller detected an electrical connection, but could not talk to the device.

Answer (score 2):

According to the log, the camera connects to the bus and then immediately disconnects. I'd say a power issue is most likely.

Disconnect all USB devices and plug just the webcam, see if it stays connected in that case. Try shorter cables to supply power to the Pi, or a different power supply.

If you have a multimeter, check the voltage on the 5V pin, and, if possible on USB 5V pin. Any value below 5V is possibly bad, because the multimeter only shows the average value, and you need safety margin to cover eventual voltage dips.

Try plugging the webcam in each of the USB ports, perhaps one of them is damaged and the electrical contact inside is intermittent.

Comment: Although it seems right but the camera works on other laptop and the other port on raspberry pi works fine with all USB devices.

I'll try to check with multimeter.

Comment: @user3275095 Does the Pi work fine also with power-hungry USB devices like HDDs?

Comment: For HDDs I have powered USB hub.

Comment: @user3275095 Why not use it for the webcam as well?

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't makes a difference. Same issue.

Comment: I checked with multimeter. I am getting 5v both from USB plugged into pi or powered USB hub.